# Highlighting a particular section of image using HTML/JS

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am creating a simple ASP.NET web application. I have an image of different machinery combined/joined together in one single image and I want to highlight these machineries with a different color (RED/GREEN/YELLOW) depending on their running status which I am obtaining from an API call with jquery.

I have created an image map using https://www.image-map.net/ and divided my image into 5 sections. I am using (https://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) MapHilight which is helping me to highlight different image maps and it is working properly on a full-screen resolution. The problem is that it doesn't support responsiveness, the moment I resize my browser, as the image map coordinates don't get change automatically according to browser size, the highlight tends to be of a static size and doesn't matches with the image map. Also when the browser size becomes very small, it replicates the image 2-3 times on the same page.

**Following is the image which appears in the full resolution window size.**
[image: Image in full resolution]

```
------------------------HTML CODE---------------------------------

   <img src="~/Content/Images/Picture1.png" width="1500" height="789" id="plant-image1" class="img-responsive map" usemap="#image-map" />
            <map name="image-map" id="map_id">
                <area id="CC1" target="" alt="caster" title="Caster" href="/Home/Caster" coords="-1,86,31,70,11,36,33,23,65,62,98,41,79,11,100,1,133,34,186,19,217,39,1,119" shape="poly">
                <area id="furnace" target="" alt="furnace" title="furnace" href="" coords="51,140,47,105,87,91,97,127,127,112,121,79,158,64,163,102,194,86,471,182,349,257,56,153" shape="poly">
                <area id="HSM" target="" alt="hsm" title="Hot Strip Mill" href="" coords="347,260,626,363,721,241,493,168,348,260" shape="poly">
                <area id="cooling line" target="" alt="cooling line" title="cooling line" href="" coords="647,336,925,433,973,338,711,255" shape="poly">
                <area id="downcoiler" target="" alt="downcoiler" title="downcoiler" href="" coords="910,458,972,344,1089,386,1060,511" shape="poly">
            </map>
     <div id="caster-title">Caster</div>
            <div id="caster-pos"></div>
            <div id="tunnelFurnace-title">Tunnel Furnace</div>
            <div id="pos2"></div>
            <div id="hsm-title">Finishing Mill</div>
            <div id="hsm-pos"></div>
            <div id="cooling-title">Cooling Section</div>
            <div id="pos4"></div>
            <div id="coiler-title">Down Coiler</div>
            <div id="pos5"></div>

<div class="col-lg-4 border-right">
    <div id="runstate"></div>
```

```
----------------------JavaScript-----------------------------------

function data1()
{
    $.ajax({
    url: '../api/runstate',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('table');
        var $cap = $('<caption> Running Status of Different Production Line </caption>');
        var $header = $('<thead/>').html('<tr><th>Production Line Name</th><th>Run State</th><th>Run State Duration</th><th>Line Stop Begin</th><th>Line Stop End</th></tr>');
        $table.append($cap);
        $table.append($header);
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            var $row = $('<tr/>');
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.prod_line_name));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.run_state));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.run_state_duration));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.line_stop_begin));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.line_stop_end));
            $table.append($row);
        });
        $('#runstate').html($table);
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var equip = data[i].prod_line_name;
            var x = $('#' + equip).data('maphilight') || {}
            if (data[i].run_state == "RUN") {
                x.fillColor = '32CD32'
                if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'CC1') {
                    document.getElementById("caster-pos").innerHTML = "Running";
                    document.getElementById("caster-pos").style.color = "green";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'Furnace') {
                    document.getElementById("pos2").innerHTML = "Running";
                    document.getElementById("pos2").style.color = "green";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'HSM') {
                    document.getElementById("hsm-pos").innerHTML = "Running";
                    document.getElementById("hsm-pos").style.color = "green";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'FinishingMill') {
                    document.getElementById("pos4").innerHTML = "Running";
                    document.getElementById("pos4").style.color = "green";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'DownCoiler') {
                    document.getElementById("pos5").innerHTML = "Running";
                    document.getElementById("pos5").style.color = "green";
                }
            }
            else if (data[i].run_state == "SLOW DOWN") {
                x.fillColor = 'FFFF00';
                if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'CC1') {
                    document.getElementById("caster-pos").innerHTML = "On-Hold";
                    document.getElementById("caster-pos").style.color = "yellow";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'Furnace') {
                    document.getElementById("pos2").innerHTML = "On-Hold";
                    document.getElementById("pos2").style.color = "yellow";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'HSM') {
                    document.getElementById("hsm-pos").innerHTML = "On-Hold";
                    document.getElementById("hsm-pos").style.color = "yellow";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'FinishingMill') {
                    document.getElementById("pos4").innerHTML = "On-Hold";
                    document.getElementById("pos4").style.color = "yellow";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'DownCoiler') {
                    document.getElementById("pos5").innerHTML = "On-Hold";
                    document.getElementById("pos5").style.color = "yellow";
                }
            }
            else if (data[i].run_state == "STOP") {
                x.fillColor = 'FF0000';
                if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'CC1') {
                    document.getElementById("caster-pos").innerHTML = "Stopped";
                    document.getElementById("caster-pos").style.color = "red";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'Furnace') {
                    document.getElementById("pos2").innerHTML = "Stopped";
                    document.getElementById("pos2").style.color = "red";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'HSM') {
                    document.getElementById("hsm-pos").innerHTML = "Stopped";
                    document.getElementById("hsm-pos").style.color = "red";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'FinishingMill') {
                    document.getElementById("pos4").innerHTML = "Stopped";
                    document.getElementById("pos4").style.color = "red";
                }
                else if (data[i].prod_line_name == 'DownCoiler') {
                    document.getElementById("pos5").innerHTML = "Stopped";
                    document.getElementById("pos5").style.color = "red";
                }
            }
            x.fillOpacity = '0.3';
            $('#' + equip).data('maphilight', x);
        }
        $('.map').maphilight({ alwaysOn: true, stroke: 0 });
```

**Following is the image which appears after browser resizes**
[image: Image after resizing]

I have also tried (http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html) so that my image map become responsive but it doesn't work with MapHilight very well.

I am hoping to divide my image into different sections and highlight them with different color depending on their running status information which I am obtaining from the API and being responsive.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: You need to show code and what you have tried so far and be specific about what isn't working. Right now your question is basically "stuff you can't see doesn't work right", so it's hard to help.

Comment: @mplungjan Just updated my question with code, hope this will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using Image Mapster jquery. I have followed the following steps which are available on the following link http://blog.thehumangeo.com/making-imagemaps-fun.html